# how to convert a mixed series to float

Tags: pandas

How can I convert following pandas series to floats:

```
s = pd.Series(['2,3', 5.1, '', '3.2'])
```

I tried s.to_float() but got a ValueError: Unable to parse string "2,3" at position 0

Comment: dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns

Comment: Do you want to treat `2,3` as `2.3`?

Comment: indeed I want 2,3 as 2.3

Comment: @EdChum nope, I have mixed formats for decimals, with ',' and '.' as decimal point

Answer (score 1):

Cast the Series to `str` if necessary, then [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) the comma with a decimal, then you can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric):

```
In[24]:
s = pd.to_numeric(s.astype(str).str.replace(',','.'))
s

Out[24]: 
0    2.3
1    5.1
2    NaN
3    3.2
dtype: float64
```

If the dtype of the Series is already `str` then the `astype(str)` step can be skipped, but I'm assuming you have a more complicated real dataset issue